# My for loop doesn't work?

Tags: c, linear-algebra

I'm creating a program that solves linear systems using the Gauss-Jordan method by following this algorithm:

```
for each row ri of the matrix (i from 1 to n)
        replace ri with ri / rii
        for each row rk of the matrix (k!=i)
                replace rk with rk - rki * ri
```

Apparently I'm not doing it right because only the first element in the row is being divided by itself. I'm still new to C, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (m = 0; m < n+1; m++) {
        if (matrix[k][m] < TOLERANCE) {
            printf("Error, pivot is 0\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        matrix[k][m] = matrix[k][m] / matrix[k][k];
    }

    for (l = 0; l != k; l++) {
        printMatrix(n, n+1, matrix);
        for (o = 0; o < n+1; o++) {
            matrix[l][o] = matrix[l][o] - matrix[l][k] * matrix[k][o];
        }
    }
}
```

Any other input? It's still not quite right and I'm pulling my hair out lol

Comment: What are `n` and `m`? Just variables being passed into the function?

Comment: n is the number of rows in the system. m is a counter. It is supposed to be an augmented matrix, so there are n+1 columns as well.

Answer (score 3):

For a start, the `l != k` in your inner loop is a continue condition. In other words, that loop will *exit* when `l` is equal to `k`.

That's not how it works in the original code. It keeps going for all other values of `l`.

You can use something like this instead:

```
for(l = 0; l < n; l++) {
    if (l != k) {
        printMatrix(n, n+1, matrix);
        for (o = 0; o < n+1; o++) {
            matrix[l][o] = matrix[l][o] - matrix[l][k] * matrix[k][o];
        }
    }
}
```

And, as an aside, you should probably try to move away from one-letter variable names, *especially* `l`, which can bite you quite badly the first time you mistake it for `1` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You will be dividing `matrix[k][k]` by itself (thus setting it to 1) and then dividing the rest of the row by 1. Use a temporary variable to store the original pivot instead of using `matrix[k][k]`

**Edit:** While the above is a bug in the code, that's probably not causing what you are experiencing, as others have pointed out, you also need to use `continue`, rather than terminating the loop when `l=k`.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
for(l = 0; l != k; l++){
```

with

```
for(l = 0; l < n; l++){
  if (l == k) continue;
```

The first one stops as soon as `l` reaches `k`, so only processes rows `0..k-1`. The second one processes rows `0..n-1` except row `k` (which fits to your pseudocode "`for each row rk of the matrix (k!=i)`")

Also:

```
for(m = 0; m < n+1; m++){
```

This means you have a matrix with n rows and n+1 columns, is this correct? If it is, everything else looks good as far as I can say.